# Docker compose hangs when installing kerberos

Tags: node.js, docker, boot2docker, docker-compose

I'm using the following files for a small node project.

```
# dockerfile
FROM node:0.12.6
ADD . /code
WORKDIR /code
RUN npm i
```

```
# docker-compose.yaml
web:
  build: .
  command: npm start
  environment:
    EXPRESS_PORT: 5000
  ports:
   - "5000:5000"
  volumes:
   - .:/code
  links:
   - redis
   - mongo
redis:
  image: redis
mongo:
  image: mongo
```

`docker-compose up` proceeds as normal until one of my dependencies `mongoose` tries to install kerberos:

```
  kerberos@0.0.12 install /code/node_modules/mongoose/node_modules/mongodb/node_modules/mongodb-core/node_modules/kerberos
(node-gyp rebuild 2> builderror.log) || (exit 0)
```

After this the install seems to hang for 15+ minutes. I have seen this succeed once, but then hang on a successive install of another dependency.

Are there any ways to mitigate this, or at the very least debug what is going on?

I'm using the latest versions of `boot2docker` and `docker-compose`